# Liferay Elastic Search: Query fields using StringQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay

I need to query two fields from elastic search using query_string: e.g. name and age.

It works if I do it via the following query directly to Liferay's Elastic Search:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ 
        { "match": { "recordSetId": "123" }}, 
        { "query_string": 
            { 
                "query": "Maximil*",
                "fields": ["name", "age"]
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can send the above query from Liferay Java Code?
I would need something like:

```
StringQuery query = queries.string(searchTerms);
query.setFields(); // this does not exist...
```

Comment: Hi Michelle Can't you use the client library provided by elasticsearch ?

Comment: Hi, I am using the Liferay API for Elastic Search, with library do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
searchContext.setStart(QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
searchContext.setEnd(QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
searchContext.setUserId(userId);
searchContext.setEntryClassNames("Enter the name of the class you want to get data from");
```

> (Like : "JournalArticle.class.getName()")

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQueryImpl();
query.add(new TermQueryImpl("name", "Maximil*",BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);
query.add(new TermQueryImpl("age","Maximil*",BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);

Hits hits = IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, query);
List<Document> document = hits.toList();
```